# Send different response from webhook in nodejs (Dialogflow)

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I'm new using Dialogflow. I have a webhook in nodejs which send a response to users when they ask for information, I would like to send a different response if the users are using telegram, facebook, line... by now I always send the same.
This is my webhook:

```
"use strict";

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const restService = express();

restService.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
})
);

restService.use(bodyParser.json());

restService.post("/webhook", function(req, res) {
var speech =
req.body.result &&
req.body.result.parameters &&
req.body.result.parameters.tipo
  ? response(req.body.result.parameters.tipo.toLowerCase())
  : "Ups... ha habido algún problema con nuestra comunicación, sorry!";
return res.json({
    speech: speech,
    displayText: speech,
    source: "webhook-echo-sample"
 });
});

let response = function(tipo){
   let response;
   switch(tipo){
       case 'daw':  response = 'http://moodle.iesgrancapitan.org/course/index.php?categoryid=7'; break;
       case 'asir':  response = 'http://moodle.iesgrancapitan.org/course/index.php?categoryid=4'; break;
       default: response = 'Vaya... Creo que algo fue mal'; break;
  }
  return response;
}

restService.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, function() {
   console.log("Server up and listening");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to add a platform specific response:

1. At your intent, scroll all the way down to responses. Next to the default, there's a plus button where you can select for which platform you want to add rich messages. If you then go to the 'Add responses' you can select from the drop down menu what your rich response should have (madia, suggestion chips etc) and then add there all the information required.
2. From your fulfillment, by adding a custom payload. I've attached the snippet below, but for more information you can visit this link https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment. And of course, don't forget to enable the fulfillment for that intent :)

```js
{
"fulfillmentText": "This is a text response",
"fulfillmentMessages": [
  {
    "card": {
      "title": "card title",
      "subtitle": "card text",
      "imageUri": "https://assistant.google.com/static/images/molecule/Molecule-Formation-stop.png",
      "buttons": [
        {
          "text": "button text",
          "postback": "https://assistant.google.com/"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
],
"source": "example.com",
"payload": {
  "google": {
    "expectUserResponse": true,
    "richResponse": {
      "items": [
        {
          "simpleResponse": {
            "textToSpeech": "this is a simple response"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "facebook": {
    "text": "Hello, Facebook!"
  },
  "slack": {
    "text": "This is a text response for Slack."
  }
},
"outputContexts": [
  {
    "name": "projects/${PROJECT_ID}/agent/sessions/${SESSION_ID}/contexts/context name",
    "lifespanCount": 5,
    "parameters": {
      "param": "param value"
    }
  }
],
"followupEventInput": {
  "name": "event name",
  "languageCode": "en-US",
  "parameters": {
    "param": "param value"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The fulfillment was what I needed :)